# How to convert raw data to image in android?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmapimage, raw-data

I am trying to create fingerprint image from scanner. When i scan finger from scanner then getting raw data but i can't convert to image. I try many links but my problem has not been solved. So how to convert raw to image in android?
Any 3rd party library available?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the raw bytes for the image, you can do something like this:

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(rawData));
```

Comment: I just try your code. But I am getting error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels" @Buddy